# How to match element fired by an other element. Understanding hierarchy

Tags: jquery

I have a table dinamically generated by a mySQL query as this:

```
|    title    | Published |      Delete     |
---------------------------------------------
|  Review_1   |   Yes     | click_to_delete |
|  Review_2   |   Yes     | click_to_delete |
|  Review_3   |   Yes     | click_to_delete |
```

Each table row is builded - for example - with the following code (id is 1 only for example):

```
<tr>
    <td><a class="editlink" id="1" href="#">Review_1</a><td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td><a class="delete_review" id="1" href="#"><img src="remove.png"/></a></td>
</tr>
```

I would like that when the user clicks - for example - the first link 'click_to_delete' an alert pops up saying that his is going to delete the review 'Review_1'.

So I want to get the TEXT of the Review_1 link when the users clicks the corresponding 'click_to_delete'.

I tried with the following code:

```
$(".delete_review").click(function() {
    var index = $(".editlink").index(this);
    var item_name = $(".editlink").eq(index).text();
    alert(item_name);
}
```

I don't understand why this line returns correctly the position of the element

```
var index = $(".editlink").index(this);
```

while this one does not return the text of the link:

```
var item_name = $(".editlink").eq(index).text();
```

of course **$(this)** is not usefull in this case because the event is not fired by the same element.

Comment: id="1" is assigned multiple times, that won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can traverse the DOM tree up to the `td` element using [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) (or [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/), but bear in mind that it would then break if you happened to add more elements in between) and then use [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) and [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the first sibling:

```
var item_name = $(this).closest("td").siblings().eq(0).text();
```

The `index` method returns the index of the element *relative to its siblings*. In your case, the link has no siblings, so the index should always be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the DOM traversal methods instead.

For example:

```
$(".delete_review").click(function() {
    var item_name = $(this).closest('tr').find('.editlink').text();
    alert(item_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/yX94V/